# Showing $8(\arctan(\sqrt2-1)) = \pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

My friend is saying  $$8(\arctan(\sqrt2-1)) = \pi$$
I know $4\arctan(1) = \pi$

I thought of $4\arctan(\sqrt2-1) + 4\arctan(\sqrt2-1)$

But I got stuck somewhere

How to solve?

Comment: I don't see any variables for which to solve.

Comment: This comes down to computing $\tan \left(\frac {\pi}8\right)$ which you can do via the half-angle formulas.

Comment: Actually I thought I may get answers by solving $arctan(\sqrt2-1)$ as $arctan(a) + arctan(b)$. But after seeing the answers from members it is so simple to solve. Thank you very much for the community

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351592/show-that-tan-pi-over-8-sqrt-2-1, since that question asks for a proof using a specific approach.

Answer (score 7):

So you have to prove $$\tan {\pi\over 8} = \sqrt{2}-1$$

Notice that $$1= \tan (2\cdot {\pi\over 8}) = {2\tan {\pi\over 8}\over 1-\tan ^2{\pi\over 8}}$$

and solve it on $\tan {\pi\over 8}$.

Answer (score 6):

After taking the $ \tan $ on both sides you get:
$$ \tan\frac{\pi}{8} = \sqrt{2}-1 $$
Note these two double angle formulas $ \sin2x = 2\sin x \cos x $ and $ \cos 2x = 2\cos^2x-1 $. Now we have:
$$ \tan\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{8}}{\cos\frac{\pi}{8}} =  \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{8}}{\cos\frac{\pi}{8}}  \cdot \frac{\cos\frac{\pi}{8}}{\cos\frac{\pi}{8}} = \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{4}}{1+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{1+\sqrt{2}/2} = \sqrt{2} - 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is saying  $$8(\arctan(\sqrt2-1)) = \pi$$
in other words removing inverse function he is saying 
$$  (\sqrt2-1)=\tan \frac{\pi}{8}=t $$
that you can say using double angle formula for tan
$$\tan \pi/4 = \frac{2t}{1-t^2} $$
which is same thing as saying
$$ 1=\frac{2 (\sqrt2-1)}{1-(3-2\sqrt2)}$$
thats same thing as saying ... after cancelling $2$ in numerator & denominator:
$$ 1=\frac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt2-1}$$
So he is right.